# Loop to extract data

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I want to import data in .out text file to an Excel sheet.

I may have 10+ output files that are organised in the same way so I want to make a loop. I used PowerQuery.

The txt files names are Compr1, Compr2...

Without this line I have no problems but nothing shows up in Excel.

```
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

```vb
Sub BONJOUR()

Dim chemin As String
Dim querie As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 3

    chemin = "C:\Users\matth\Desktop\OUTPUT FILES\Compr" & i
    querie = "quera" & i
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add name:=querie, Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""chemin""),[Delimiter="","", Columns=3, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Kept Range of Rows"" = Table.Range(#""Changed Type"",2109" & _
        ",20)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Split Column by Delimiter"" = Table.SplitColumn(#""Kept Range of Rows"", ""Column1"", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("" * "", QuoteStyle.Csv), {""Column1.1"", ""Column1.2"", ""Column1.3"", ""Column1.4"", ""Column1.5"", ""Column1.6""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type1"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Split Column by Delimiter"",{{""Column1.1"", type text}, {""Col" & _
        "umn1.2"", type text}, {""Column1.3"", type text}, {""Column1.4"", type text}, {""Column1.5"", type text}, {""Column1.6"", type text}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Columns"" = Table.RemoveColumns(#""Changed Type1"",{""Column1.1""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Columns"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=querie;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [queries]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = querie
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("C27").Select
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Do the files have the extension `.out` like `Compr1.out` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the variables outside the quotes here `Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & chemin & """)` and `Location=" & querie & ";Extended Properties` and `Array("SELECT * FROM [" & querie & "]")`

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub BONJOUR()

    Dim chemin As String, querie As String
    Dim q As Object, i As Integer
    Dim PQ As String, f As String
    
    Const DOSSIER = "C:\Users\matth\Desktop\OUTPUT FILES\"
    
    ' power query
    PQ = "    #'Changed Type' = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{'Column1', type text}, " & vbCrLf & _
    "{'Column2', type text}, {'Column3', type text}})," & vbCrLf & _
    "    #'Kept Range of Rows' = Table.Range(#'Changed Type',2109,20)," & vbCrLf & _
    "    #'Split Column by Delimiter' = Table.SplitColumn(#'Kept Range of Rows', 'Column1', " & vbCrLf & _
    "Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(' * ', QuoteStyle.Csv), {'Column1.1', 'Column1.2', 'Column1.3'," & vbCrLf & _
    "'Column1.4', 'Column1.5', 'Column1.6'})," & vbCrLf & _
    "    #'Changed Type1' = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#'Split Column by Delimiter',{{'Column1.1', type text}," & vbCrLf & _
    " {'Column1.2', type text}, {'Column1.3', type text}, {'Column1.4', type text}, " & vbCrLf & _
    "{'Column1.5', type text}, {'Column1.6', type text}})," & vbCrLf & _
    "    #'Removed Columns' = Table.RemoveColumns(#'Changed Type1',{'Column1.1'})" & vbCrLf & _
    "in " & vbCrLf & _
    "    #'Removed Columns'"
    PQ = Replace(PQ, "'", """")
    
    For i = 1 To 3
    
        chemin = DOSSIER & "Compr" & i
        querie = "quera" & i
        
        ' check if existing
        For Each q In ActiveWorkbook.Queries
            If q.Name = querie Then
                q.Delete
                MsgBox querie & " recreated"
            End If
        Next
       
        '  query formula
        f = "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & chemin & """)," & _
            "[Delimiter="","", Columns=3, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & vbCrLf & PQ
                  
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=querie, Formula:=f
        
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
            "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & querie & ";Extended Properties=""""" _
            , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
            .CommandType = xlCmdSql
            .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & querie & "]")
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .PreserveColumnInfo = True
            .ListObject.DisplayName = querie
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
        
        Range("C27").Select
    Next
       
End Sub
```

Comment: 0


Wow! Thanks a lot for your help! It works, when there is no .out extension to the file. So i just modified this line :

chemin = DOSSIER & "Compr" & i
by

chemin = DOSSIER & "Compr" & i & ".out"
Thanks a lot. Monday I'll try to add something to modify the name of the sheet by the name of the file but shouldn't be very hard.

I appreciate the help! Matthieu